# How to get the brightest area from webcam in Emgu CV C#?

Tags: c#, camera, stream, emgucv, brightness

I'm using `Emgu CV` library in `C#` and I can successfully display the webcam in a PictureBox. I want to set the brightness of the camera dynamically by:

```
Visible_capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Brightness, Convert.ToInt32(Value));
```

I need to get the brightest spot on the picture and change the camera brightness setting. I don't need the average brightness.

[image: Example application that shows maximum brightness]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using grayscale or looking for the maximum of any channel it looks like `Mat.MinMax` might be a good choice. You can using something like the following:

```
image.MinMax(out _, out double[] maxValues, out _, out _);
```

And because you're only interested in the maximum value not all their locations the result will be in `maxValues[0]`. I thought it would probably be faster to use `image.GetRawData().Max()` so wrote a rough benchmark in LINQPad to compare for a sample image:

```
void Main()
{
    const int testIterations = 1000;
    string imageUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/samples/data/orange.jpg";
    string imagePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(imageUrl));
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(imageUrl, imagePath);
    }
    using (Mat image = CvInvoke.Imread(imagePath, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Grayscale))
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < testIterations; i++)
        {
            image.MinMax(out _, out double[] maxValues, out _, out _);
            if (i == testIterations - 1)
            {
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Using Mat.MinMax: {maxValues[0]}, elapsed {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
        }
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < testIterations; i++)
        {

            var max = image.GetRawData().Max();
            if (i == testIterations - 1)
            {
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Using Mat.GetRawData().Max(): {max}, elapsed {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
        }
        CvInvoke.Imshow("Test", image);
    }
}
```

But the result I got after a few runs were showing that the `MinMax` method was consistently quite a bit faster, presumably because of some overhead passing the data back from the unmanaged code, but you should probably compare for your own application:

```
Using Mat.MinMax: 253, elapsed 691 ms
Using Mat.GetRawData().Max(): 253, elapsed 3760 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the brightness of all pixels, then selecting the highest value?

Comment: Not actually, I'm looking for a fast method and I think this could take much time for every frame.

Comment: You should at least try until you find a better solution.